# Unexpected arrayIndexOutofBound Exception in a game using Andengine

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine, game-physics

I am making a game on andengine. A car moving from bottom to top (Across the road), many cars are coming through the road. I want to save the single car by touching and destroying the other cars. I can get the collisions. But when I touch and destroy other cars, i get an exception ArrayOutOfBound after destroying two or three cars. What may be the problem? Thanks in advance

```
Iterator<Sprite> targets;


public void addTarget() {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int x = (int) mCamera.getWidth() + mTargetTextureRegion.getWidth();
    int minY = mTargetTextureRegion.getHeight();
    int maxY = (int) (mCamera.getHeight() - mTargetTextureRegion
            .getHeight());
    int rangeY = maxY - minY;
    int y = rand.nextInt(rangeY) + minY;
    Sprite target = new Sprite(x, y, mTargetTextureRegion.deepCopy()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

            System.out.println("Touched");
             removeSprite(this, targets);

            count--;

            return mChildrenIgnoreUpdate;

        }
    };
    mMainScene.registerTouchArea(target);
    mMainScene.setTouchAreaBindingEnabled(true);

    mMainScene.attachChild(target);
    int minDuration = 10;
    int maxDuration = 20;
    int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
    int actualDuration = rand.nextInt(rangeDuration) + minDuration;
    MoveXModifier mod = new MoveXModifier(actualDuration, target.getX(),
            -target.getWidth());
    target.registerEntityModifier(mod.deepCopy());
    TargetsToBeAdded.add(target);

}

public void removeSprite(final Sprite _sprite, Iterator it) {
    runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mMainScene.detachChild(_sprite);
        }
    });
    it.remove();
}

private void createSpriteSpawnTimeHandler() {
    if (count <= 2) {
        TimerHandler spriteTimerHandler;
        float mEffectSpawnDelay = 1f;
        spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(mEffectSpawnDelay, true,
                new ITimerCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

                        count++;
                        addTarget();

                    }
                });

        getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler);
    }
}

IUpdateHandler detect = new IUpdateHandler() {
    @Override
    public void reset() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        targets = targetLL.iterator();
        Sprite _target;
        while (targets.hasNext()) {
            _target = targets.next();
            if (_target.getX() <= -_target.getWidth()) {
                removeSprite(_target, targets);
            }

            if (_target.collidesWith(player)) {
                System.out.println("Collission occured");
                // break;

            }

        }
        targetLL.addAll(TargetsToBeAdded);
        TargetsToBeAdded.clear();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

it mostly occur in update thread of the game it is due to detach children calls. What I did was surround the mupdate handler with try catch. I didnt had time to go for the problem :)